# HTTP Redirects - Javascript or Flask?

Tags: javascript, redirect, flask

A timed redirect is all of three lines of code, so where it 'lives' is not life or death, but writing it either in Python or Javascript is the nature of the question.

I'm using Flask to serve some stuff, and whenever a page changes or a co-worker's bookmark is out of date or wrong because reasons, there's a polite 404 page and a timed redirect (because apparently, no one reads the "click here to go to the index" link and would rather email me asking what to do because they are lost... sigh).  While a simple redirect to `/index` is probably not going to be subject to dynamic changes like some of my other content - and my app is very small to boot - I'm guessing there's a right way and a *righter* way to do this, especially as one scales to bigger projects.

Especially considering that a redirect should be more dynamic - maybe I'll not always want to treat a 404 the same way under varying circumstances, like when a user expects supplementary content in a pop-up window but they get a 404 and a redirect where a different response from my app would be more fitting.  This seems like a situation where Flask should handle the redirect, as opposed to just relying on serving a 404 template with a three-line timed redirect in the Javascript - right?

It's also sort of a separation of concerns question.  I *could* do a lot with the Flask side of things, but putting code where it belongs is better than putting it where it's convenient, especially when it comes time to change things up.  So even though a `return redirect(url_for('theRightPageAtTheRightTime'))` sure looks nice, I'm not educated enough to know if that is where it *belongs*.  Does it belong in the `Flask` app?  Or should my redirect logic be left in .js files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking here, but there is not way to serve a 404 page and then redirect the user without them either:

1) Clicking a link.

2) You writing Javascript to do it.

Once the 404 page is returned to the user, your server side stack can no longer do anything to redirect the user.

Comment: @Ian Yeah that is an option as well I suppose. It is generally considered bad practice, but I suppose its no different than using Javascript to redirect the user in this case.

Comment: I think it's quite different in the case that it doesn't require JavaScript to be enabled (although I don't expect many people to have it disabled). Still, it's another option. Why is it considered bad practice?

Comment: @Ian http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-CORE-TECHS/#auto-page-refresh  As I said it really is no different from Javascript in this use case.

Comment: Indeed, this was just the cleanest way to do things.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO if you serve a 404 page, any redirection following that must be done in the client side(perhaps redirect them to the home page, to a search page or whatnot). Server redirection must be done in other cases.